# A more elegant way to cluster sorted characters together?

Tags: python, sorting

Suppose, I want to sort characters in a string by their frequency.

```
def frequencySort(self, s: str) -> str:
    
    freq = {}
    
    for i in s:
        if i in freq:
            freq[i] += 1
        else:
            freq[i] = 1
    
    print(freq)
    
    sorted_chars = sorted(s, key = lambda x : -freq[x])
    
    return "".join(sorted_chars)
```

However, for inputs where some characters have equal frequency, these characters end up intermingled together in the output.

E.g., for input `loveleetcode` the code above outputs `eeeelolovtcd` whereas it should output `eeeeoollvtcd` or `eeeelloovtcd` (o's and l's should be clustered together, not intermixed).

So, I add a tie breaker that uses a fraction of the character's ASCII code (end's up being less than one, so guaranteed not to overpower next most frequent char):

```
def frequencySort(self, s: str) -> str:
    
    freq = {}
    
    for i in s:
        if i in freq:
            freq[i] += 1
        else:
            freq[i] = 1
    
    # Tie-breaker:
    
    for i in freq:
        freq[i] += ord(i) / 1000
    
    sorted_chars = sorted(s, key = lambda x : -freq[x])
    
    return "".join(sorted_chars)
```

This works fine, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant (pythonic) way to enforce clustering of similar characters during the sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the sort key to a tuple that includes the character itself.

```
def frequencySort(self, s: str) -> str:
    freq = {}
    for i in s:
        if i in freq:
            freq[i] += 1
        else:
            freq[i] = 1
    
    sorted_chars = sorted(s, key=lambda x: (-freq[x], x))
    return "".join(sorted_chars)
```

Now, when `sorted()` encounters two different characters with the same count, it'll use the next element of the tuple to sort them. Since the next element is the character itself, the same characters will be sorted next to each other.

```
>>> solution.frequencySort("loveleetcode")
'eeeelloocdtv'
```

Unrelated note: you can use `collections.Counter` instead of creating a dict and counting the characters.

```
freq = collections.Counter(s)
```

instead of

```
freq = {}
for i in s:
    if i in freq:
        freq[i] += 1
    else:
        freq[i] = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `collections.Counter` and its `most_common` method that returns tuples of (char, count) sorted by count:

```
from collections import Counter

def frequencySort(s: str) -> str:
    counts = Counter(s)
    return ''.join([char * count for char, count in counts.most_common()])

print(frequencySort("loveleetcode"))
# 'eeeelloovtcd'
```